# Development and Distribution certificate for iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, certificate

I am building an iPhone app that will be submitted to the App Store. I am a bit confused about Development and Distribution certificates that you get from Apple.

1. Do I need to install both?  Why are both needed?
2. Does this mean that when I am ready to distribute that I need to sign the app with the Distribution certificate and when i am debugging, it should be signed with a Development certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need development certificate for development, distribution is needed: 
a) when you are doing ad-hoc distribution to multiple iphones/ipod touches. (this requires you to be enrolled in $299 dev program, you can also submit to app-store with this.)
b) Or when you want to submit your application to app-store for distribution (this requires you to be in $99 program)

You can start with development first and install the deployment only when you distribute or submit to app-store.

Comment: Yup, this pretty much sums it up. I just released an application, and I didn't use/worry about the distribution cert until it was time to distribute. I then changed certs, built, and submit.

Comment: FTR, Ad Hoc profiles are not specific to the Enterprise Program, they can be used with the Standard Program $99/year too.  See this question for more of an explanation about the programs available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876333/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-an-iphone-app-into-the-app-store-closed

Comment: What if I develop using a development certificate of one account and distribute using another account's distribution certificate? In that case, can I just create the dist. cert. of that other account and install or do I need to create and install a dev. cert. for that other  account too?

Answer (score 2):

You can still distribute your iphone app using ad-hoc distribution with the Standard ($99) memberships, for beta-testing.